# Dúvida em CSS, placeholder

Tags: html, css, placeholder

Tenho esta seguinte página de login:
https://jsfiddle.net/rafael_breno/qzkgqt9h/
Está simples do jeito que esperava, porém quando eu insiro qualquer informação nos campos(input), o placeholder volta para o campos quando vou para o próximo campo, como poderia resolver isto?

Comment: Vc está usando label e não plaeholder. Mas dá pra brincar usando uma função js

Comment: Você consegue resolver isso com JavaScript/JQuery.
Dá uma olhada nesse exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/Reinaldo_henrique/a5vnekjo/
Encontrei esta solução neste vídeo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PBGfqGANYNI

Answer (score 2):

Vc pode resolver isso colocando `required` no `input` e depois fazendo um estilo pro `input:valid` Não sei se vai resolver pro seu caso, mas da uma olhada no exemplo abaixo que está funcionando certinho.

```css
* { box-sizing:border-box; }

body {
 font-family: Helvetica;
 background: #eee;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

hgroup { 
 text-align:center;
 margin-top: 4em;
}

h1, h3 { font-weight: 300; }

h1 { color: #636363; }

h3 { color: #4a89dc; }

form {
 width: 380px;
 margin: 4em auto;
 padding: 3em 2em 2em 2em;
 background: #fafafa;
 border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
 box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.14902) 0px 1px 1px 0px,rgba(0,0,0,0.09804) 0px 1px 2px 0px;
}

.group { 
 position: relative; 
 margin-bottom: 45px; 
}

input {
 font-size: 18px;
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 5px;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 display: block;
 background: #fafafa;
 color: #636363;
 width: 100%;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 0;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #757575;
}

input:focus { outline: none; }


/* Label */

label {
 color: #999; 
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: normal;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
 left: 5px;
 top: 10px;
 -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}


/* active */

input:focus ~ label, input.used ~ label {
 top: -20px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(.75);
          transform: scale(.75); left: -2px;
 /* font-size: 14px; */
 color: #4a89dc;
}

input:valid ~ label, input.used ~ label {
 top: -20px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(.75);
          transform: scale(.75); left: -2px;
 /* font-size: 14px; */
 color: green;
}



/* Underline */

.bar {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
}

.bar:before, .bar:after {
 content: '';
 height: 2px; 
 width: 0;
 bottom: 1px; 
 position: absolute;
 background: #4a89dc; 
 -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease; 
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.bar:before { left: 50%; }

.bar:after { right: 50%; }


/* active */

input:focus ~ .bar:before, input:focus ~ .bar:after { width: 50%; }


/* Highlight */

.highlight {
 position: absolute;
 height: 60%; 
 width: 100px; 
 top: 25%; 
 left: 0;
 pointer-events: none;
 opacity: 0.5;
}


/* active */

input:focus ~ .highlight {
 -webkit-animation: inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
         animation: inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
}


/* Animations */

@-webkit-keyframes inputHighlighter {
 from { background: #4a89dc; }
 to  { width: 0; background: transparent; }
}

@keyframes inputHighlighter {
 from { background: #4a89dc; }
 to  { width: 0; background: transparent; }
}


/* Button */

.button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  margin: .3em 0 1em 0;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #3160B6;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.15s ease;
  transition: all 0.15s ease;
}
.button:focus { outline: 0; }


/* Button modifiers */

.buttonBlue {
  background: #4a89dc;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(39, 110, 204, .5);
}

.buttonBlue:hover { background: #357bd8; }


/* Ripples container */

.ripples {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: transparent;
}


/* Ripples circle */

.ripplesCircle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}

.ripples.is-active .ripplesCircle {
  -webkit-animation: ripples .4s ease-in;
          animation: ripples .4s ease-in;
}


/* Ripples animation */

@-webkit-keyframes ripples {
  0% { opacity: 0; }

  25% { opacity: 1; }

  100% {
    width: 200%;
    padding-bottom: 200%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes ripples {
  0% { opacity: 0; }

  25% { opacity: 1; }

  100% {
    width: 200%;
    padding-bottom: 200%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

footer { text-align: center; }

footer p {
 color: #888;
 font-size: 13px;
 letter-spacing: .4px;
}

footer a {
 color: #4a89dc;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-transition:all .2s ease;
 transition: all .2s ease;
}

footer a:hover {
 color: #666;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

footer img {
 width: 80px;
 -webkit-transition:all .2s ease;
 transition: all .2s ease;
}

footer img:hover { opacity: .83; }

footer img:focus , footer a:focus { outline: none; }
```

```html
<body>
  <hgroup>
   <h1><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="web/images/logo.png"></a></h1>
   <h3>Gerenciador de OS</h3>
  </hgroup>
  <form action="verifica_login.php" method="post">
   <div class="group">
    <input type="text" name="usuario" syze="20" maxlength="40" required><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
    <label>User</label>
   </div>
   <div class="group">
    <input required type="password" name="senha" syze="20" maxlength="40"><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
    <label>Password</label>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" name="button" class="button buttonBlue" value="1">Login
    <div class="ripples buttonRipples"><span class="ripplesCircle"></span></div>
   </button>
  </form>
  <footer>
  </footer>
 </body>
```

*OBS: vc ainda pode usar o `css` para fazer um estilo pro `input` quando ele for `invalide` .*

Answer (score 0):

Segue um bom exemplo para você:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/2500/1500?image=1041);
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 25rem;
  padding: 2.5rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  border-radius: 0.625rem;
}

.box h2 {
  margin: 0 0 1.875rem;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.box .inputBox {
  position: relative;
}

.box .inputBox input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.625rem 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 0.062rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.875rem;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 0.065rem solid #fff;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
}

.box .inputBox label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0.625rem 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.box .inputBox input:focus~label,
.box .inputBox input:valid~label,
.box .inputBox input:not([value=""])~label {
  top: -1.125rem;
  left: 0;
  color: #03a9f4;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}

.box input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #03a9f4;
  padding: 0.625rem 1.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 0.312rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.box input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #1cb1f5;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h2>Login</h2>
  <form>
    <div class="inputBox">
      <input type="email" name="email" required onkeyup="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);" value="">
      <label>Username</label>
    </div>
    <div class="inputBox">
      <input type="password" name="password" required value="" onkeyup="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters">
      <label>Password</label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="sign-in" value="Sign In">
  </form>
</div>
```

**Fonte**: https://codepen.io/FrankieDoodie/pen/GXWwVv